# MissingFieldException: Templated field missing in constructor

Tags: c#, templates, exception, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a 2D array class that allows for very large data sets by breaking up the data and storing it non-contiguously. However, I get a MissingFieldException inside the constructor that I fundamentally don't understand. I'm using c# with Unity.

This is the offending call:

```
 ChunkArray<int> lastData = new ChunkArray<int>(textureWidth, textureHeight);
```

The exception is "MissingFieldException: Field '.ChunkArray`1.data' not found."
The class is as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ChunkArray<T> 
{
    private const int DefaultSideDivision = 16;

    T[,][,] data;

    int xChunks;
    int yChunks;

    int subWidth;
    int subHeight;

    public int w;
    public int h;

    public ChunkArray(int width, int height, int sideDivision = DefaultSideDivision) 
    {
        w = width;
        h = height;
        subWidth = width / sideDivision;
        subHeight = height / sideDivision;

        int widthRemainder = width % sideDivision;
        int heightRemainder = height % sideDivision;

        xChunks = (widthRemainder == 0) ? sideDivision : sideDivision + 1;
        yChunks = (heightRemainder == 0) ? sideDivision : sideDivision + 1;

        data = new T[xChunks, yChunks][,];

        for (int i = 0; i < xChunks; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < yChunks; j++) 
            {
                int x = (i < sideDivision) ? subWidth : widthRemainder;
                int y = (j < sideDivision) ? subHeight : heightRemainder;
                data[i, j] = new T[x,y];
            }
        }           
    }

    public T get(int x, int y)
    {
        return data[x / subWidth, y / subHeight][x % subWidth, y % subHeight];
    }

    public void set(int x,int y, T value) {
        data[x / subWidth, y / subHeight][x % subWidth, y % subHeight] = value; 
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am completely stumped. I hope I formatted this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Mono: it fails to instantiate a generic multi-dimensional array of multi-dimensional arrays. However, when I tried to replace T[,][,] with T[][] it worked, so I suggest emulating two-dimensional arrays with single-dimensional ones:

```
public class ChunkArray<T>
{
    private const int DefaultSideDivision = 16;

    T[][] internalData;

    int xChunks;
    int yChunks;

    int subWidth;
    int subHeight;

    public int w;
    public int h;

    public ChunkArray(int width, int height)
    {
        int sideDivision = DefaultSideDivision;
        w = width;
        h = height;
        subWidth = width / sideDivision;
        subHeight = height / sideDivision;

        int widthRemainder = width % sideDivision;
        int heightRemainder = height % sideDivision;

        xChunks = (widthRemainder == 0) ? sideDivision : sideDivision + 1;
        yChunks = (heightRemainder == 0) ? sideDivision : sideDivision + 1;

        internalData = new T[xChunks * yChunks][];

        for (int i = 0; i < xChunks; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < yChunks; j++)
            {
                internalData[GetFirstIndex(i,j)] = new T[subWidth * subHeight];
            }
        }
    }

    private int GetFirstIndex(int i, int j)
    {
        return i + j * xChunks;
    }

    private int GetSecondIndex(int i, int j)
    {
        return i + j * subWidth;
    }

    public T get(int x, int y)
    {
        return internalData[GetFirstIndex(x / subWidth, y / subHeight)][GetSecondIndex(x % subWidth, y % subHeight)];
    }

    public void set(int x, int y, T value)
    {
        internalData[GetFirstIndex(x / subWidth, y / subHeight)][GetSecondIndex(x % subWidth, y % subHeight)] = value;
    }
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, I've set all the data chunks to the same size, so the last chunks have some unused space.

Comment: Additionally, it looks like T[,][] also works. The bug appears to be with having a multidimensional jagged array at two levels rather than just one. Also, I'm using VS. edit: it's also worth noting it doesn't occur without the generic type.